# how can (k+1)! (k+2)-1 be (k+2)!-1?

Tags: induction, factorial

how can $(k+1)! (k+2)-1$ be $(k+2)!-1$ ? Can someone explain how it works?

I already tried to expand it but didn't work.

Comment: $n!$ verifies the recurrence relation $(n+1)!=(n+1).n!$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS the usual term is "satisfies", not "verifies"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : thank you :-)

Comment: \begin{align*}
(k+1)!(k+2)&=\left[1\times 2\times 3\times \ldots\times (k+1)\right]\times(k+2)\\
&=1\times 2\times 3\times \ldots\times (k+1)\times(k+2)\\
&=(k+2)!
\end{align*}

Comment: @projectilemotion It probably is a mistake, but was there in the original.

Answer (score 3):

Use the definition of factorial.

Since $(k+2)! = (k+2) \cdot (k+1) \cdot k \cdots 2 \cdot 1 = (k+2) \cdot (k+1)!$, you have

$$ (k+1)! (k+2) - 1 = (k+2)! - 1.$$

Unless I misunderstood your question?

Comment: okay..finally i got it..thanks a lot